# Starting Django Project

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a django project with "django-admin.exe startproject mysite ." but I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\denni\documents\ecommerce\myvenv\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\denni\Documents\Ecommerce_Site\myvenv\Scripts\django-admin.exe" startproject mysite .': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create Virtual Environment to start `Project` so all the dependencies and packages will download in your Project's Environment.

Create a New Blank Folder and open cmd or shell in that folder.

You can install it with pip :-

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Now create the virtual environment

```
virtualenv mypython
```

Activate the virtual environment

**Mac OS**

```
source mypython/bin/activate
```

**Windows**

```
mypthon\Scripts\activate
```

NOW install django using in virtual environment using pip :-

```
pip install django
```

Now create project using :-

```
django-admin startproject *project_name* .
```

Now migrate it

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Now create app :-

```
python manage.py startapp *app_name*
```

AND NOW :-

```
python manage.py runserver
```

> Note :- Don't forget DOT (.) while creating project.

Answer (score 0):

the correct command is :

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 0):

To start a django project you need the command.

django-admin startproject mysite
where mysite is the name of the project....
You can thence start apps by python manage.py startapp myapp where myapp is the name of the app.